# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Value for a model's field is generated by a function and it stays same until I restart the app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the model defined in `models.py`

```py
import os
import secrets

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    thumbnail = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='/static/blog/images/blog_thumbnails/default.png')
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    hex_token = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False, default=secrets.token_hex(8))


    def save_thumbnail(self):
        if 'thumbnail' in request.files:
            file = request.files['thumbnail']
            filename = f'{self.id}_{self.hex_token}.png'
            file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Then there's a view function in `routes.py` for adding a new `BlogPost` object which looks something like this:

```py
@admin_blueprint.route('/add_blog/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_blog():
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form['title']
        content = request.form['content']
        post = BlogPost(title=title, content=content)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        post.save_thumbnail()
        db.session.close()
        return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
    form = BlogPostForm()
    return render_template('add_blog.html', form=form)
```

The `thumbnail` field of `BlogPost` model is just path to the user-uploaded picture, the filename is generated by  the id of the `BlogPost` object plus an underscore and a random hex token and later the picture is saved with `.save()` method, however let's say user creates multiple `BlogPost` objects in one session, the filenames will have only unique id but not hex, and it's the same way from python shell as well.

For example, the generated filenames will be like this:
`1_e5d2e3623a42f117`, `2_e5d2e3623a42f117`, `3_e5d2e3623a42f117` etc...

I figured the fix would be to add a hex_token parameter to the `save_thumbnail` method, remove `hex_token` field from the model at all and instead generate it each time the view is called. this is what I mean:

```py
def save_thumbnail(self, hex_token):
        if 'thumbnail' in request.files:
            file = request.files['thumbnail']
            filename = f'{self.id}_{hex_token}.png'
            file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

and in `routes.py`

```py
@admin_blueprint.route('/add_blog/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_blog():
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form['title']
        content = request.form['content']
        post = BlogPost(title=title, content=content)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        hex_token = secret.token_hex(8) # new line

        post.save_thumbnail(hex_token)
        db.session.close()
        return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
    form = BlogPostForm()
    return render_template('add_blog.html', form=form)
```

This works, however I want to know why my initial version is behaving the way it is

Answer (score 0):

Because your class BlogPost is declared only one time as well as the attribute hex_token.

```
hex_token = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False, default=secrets.token_hex(8))
```

When you define hex_token, default value is defined only once, and it is stored inside your tables settings as default option. You cannot dynamically change default value each time when you call method of that class. That is the reason why hex_token returns the same value each time you call method of that class which use hex_token.